# Update Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables called ASI and Call and the data in the tables looks like:

Call

```
ID   Flag  Created_ON
12   1     2011-08-05 11:48:09.477
15   1     2011-08-05 11:48:09.477
18   1     2011-08-05 11:48:09.477
20   1     2011-08-05 11:48:09.477
25   1     2010-08-12 14:05:11.000
```

ASI

```
ID  Open_Date
12  2010-07-02 09:40:00.000
20  2010-08-12 14:05:11.000
18  2010-08-09 15:26:43.000
```

I want to update the Flag column in Call table with 0 where the ID is not present in ASI Table. In the above example I want ID's 15 and 25 to be 0.

Output:

```
ID   Flag  Created_ON
12   1     2011-08-05 11:48:09.477
15   0     2011-08-05 11:48:09.477
18   1     2011-08-05 11:48:09.477
20   1     2011-08-05 11:48:09.477
25   0     2010-08-12 14:05:11.000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Flag = 0
FROM Call A
LEFT JOIN ASI B
ON A.Id = B.Id
WHERE B.Id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update call set flag=0 where id not in (
  select distinct id from asi)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Call
SET Flag = 0
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM ASI)
```